# Using Path Distance to Calculate Total Accumulated Cost from Source to Destination?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I am looking to calculate the total accumulated cost associated with traveling from a source point to a destination point (please see the included figure below, green dot = source, red dot = destination). I would like to use the ArcGIS "Path Distance" tool because I am interested in including horizontal factors associated with traversal as well as friction values associated with my cost surface (the cost surface is visible in the picture).

[image]

I'd like to know if it is possible to calculate total accumulated cost to my specific destination point, instead of just creating a path distance raster that calculates accumulated cost for the entire region. I have used the path distance raster and accompanying backlink raster as inputs for a least cost path, but I am getting an error output from Arc. The error message is general, and only states "failed to execute costpath".

How do I solve this issue?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6, and can use Python if it will be of assistance.

Comment: The constant grey background suggests a constant value, would the path between these two points be a straight line?

Comment: @Hornbydd Thanks for commenting. It is very possible that this example may produce a straight line, but I can't even seem to be able to produce a cost path! Something beforehand is creating an issue I believe but i'm not sure what.